# Can "respectively" be used with a single sequence if clear to what each item refers?

Tags: word-usage

Typically, the word "respectively" is used to relate two sequences of identical lengths:

> ... expectation of finding two and three cats in the left and right room, respectively.

Meaning, in this example, that the expectation was to find two cats in the left room and three in the right room.

Now I'm wondering if omitting the latter sequence is acceptable if the reader can be expected to still understand what is meant, e.g., if this is something that has been extensively discussed before and is now only mentioned again to remind the reader.

> ... expectation of finding two and three cats, respectively.

If this is highly unusual or even completely incorrect, is there a better alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: This is wholly dependent on context. How close in the narration are the associated concepts to be paired? *We looked into the left and right rooms with the expectation of finding two and three cats, respectively*? Ok, understood. Three sentences earlier, no.

Comment: I agree with @bib's comment, which includes a natural-sounding example.  The first example in the question, however, does not sound natural to me; I'd say or write  “... expectation of finding two or three cats in the left or right room, respectively” (ie would use *or* rather than *and* in the phrase).

Answer (score 1):

«Respectively» is used when enumerating two or more items or facts that refer back to a previous statement. This previous statement is generally made within the same phrase, i.e. when no other statement is made between the original statement and the reference. I would thus advise against using «respectively» to refer to a statement that is preceded and followed by one or a set of further statements. Otherwise, I'm afraid your cats will likely never be found again.

Answer (score -1):

Example: If you have any questions, please contact Robert or Phil at 412-000-000, Extension 3555 or 3567, respectively.  You're giving the reader the information that Robert is at Extension 3555 and Phil is at Extension 3567.

Comment: Hi @Sketergurl. I don't think this answers the OP's original question, which going beyond the normal usage of respectively, which you've shown.